# log-driver=gelf does not work on CoreOS?

Tags: logging, docker, coreos, graylog

I'm currently migrating my docker server from CentOS to CoreOS. When i tried to configure the docker demon to send all log messages to a logstash by using GELF (graylog extended logging format) i got the following error from docker:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container c2522f318221b53fb360dca08c806f20b5b04b55529e89d79658d328c196c4ca: Failed to initialize logging driver: Failed to get logging factory: logger: no log driver named 'gelf' is registered
```

Q: Is docker on CoreOS compiled without gelf support?

I would like to continue using gelf because docker adds fields like the image_name to the log-messages by default.

Q: Is there another log driver that supports something like that?

EDIT:

The server:

```
Kernel Version: 4.1.7-coreos-r1
Operating System: CoreOS 766.5.0
```

And docker is

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
```

Comment: Which version of Docker and CoreOS are you using?

Comment: @joschi see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GELF logging driver was added in [Docker 1.8.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180-2015-08-11). Either you upgrade Docker (and CoreOS) or you're out of luck.